# jquery onchange event not working for file uploading in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ajaxq

I am using file uploading from php using jquery ajax method .I have achieved file uploading using submitting a form when clicked on a button but it doesn,t work for onchange event when input field is change . Here's the code i am using,

```
<div id="photo">
<img id="image" src="<?php echo $uploadedfile;?>" width=100% height=100%>
</div>
<form id="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="pick">Change Photo
<input type="file" name="files" id="upload">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="send" name="submit">
</form>
```

**jquery used**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$("form#myform").submit(function(event){

event.preventDefault();

var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

$.ajax({

url : "main.php",
type: 'POST',
datatype : "JSON",
data: formData,
async: false,
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
success: function (returndata) {

    $("#image").attr({
        'src' : returndata.uploadedfile
});

}
}); 
return false;

});

</script>
```

**php code here**

```
<?php   
$uploadedfile = "default.jpg";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if(isset($_FILES["files"]["name"])){


$filename = $_FILES["files"]["name"];   
$tmppath  = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"];
$ext = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$targetfile = "uploads/".basename($filename);

if($_FILES["files"]["size"] > 0)
{

if($ext == "jpg")
{
if(file_exists($targetfile)){

$uploadok = false;
$error = "file already exists";
}
else {

$uploadok = true;
}
}
else
{

$uploadok = false;
$error = "only jpg format is allowed";
}   
}
else {
$uploadok = false;
$error = "filesize is too short";   
}
if($uploadok == true){  
move_uploaded_file($tmppath,$targetfile);

$uploadedfile = $targetfile;
$error = "no errors!";
}else{
$uploadedfile = "default.jpg";
}
header("Content-type: text/x-json");
$data = array('error'=>$error, 'uploadedfile'=>$uploadedfile);

echo json_encode($data);
exit();
}
}
?>
```

I want to achieve this on changing only not by clicking on a button . any idea ??

Comment: Have you tried `$("#upload").on("change", function(e){...your handler...})`? Also nitpick: `$(this)[0] === this`

Comment: Yeah tried the on change but what is nitpick? @tcooc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$("form#myform").submit(function (event)
```

to this:

```
$("form#myform").change(function (event)
```

Comment: what browser are you using? When you say _"I want to achieve this on changing only not by clicking"_ do you mean that the function should be fired when you select an image?

Comment: as i change the input field , The event should be fired for should get submitted

Comment: But its working fine on button click , hold on let me update php code

Comment: look at the first `if` of your PHP: `isset($_POST['submit'])`. Thats why it doesnt work, your PHP is expecting a submit POST variable. delete that that IF and it will work

Comment: no still no change , i've added two alerts one after on change event and one after submit function but only 1st one is working that means its not going inside submit function

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3dqmyn7o/ It shows that it works. Does it work for you?

Comment: yeah alert is working fine for onchange event but now problem is  if i add another alert inside form submit function it doesn't work that means function submit is not working..

Comment: hey its working now and that was simple , I wasn,t using onchange and commentin the isset function at same time you were right. Thanks a ton it was really helpful